# Ranking a record based on a pre-calculated field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query and I am trying to figure out how to rank 
in the DENSE_RANK area by 'Status'. Status is a row from a case when statement when the current month measure is greater than the 6 mos average. 
Basically I want to rank the largest to smallest 'GoalAchieved' status partitioned by territory by Order by sum(revenue). Same with the inprogress status.

So each territory should have a rank of 1,2,3,4 for goalachieved status and the same thing for 'Inprogress' Status.

Any help would be awesome.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ClinLocationID, Terrioty,
ClinLocationName, Round(Sum(revenue),2)

CASE WHEN CM > LastSixmosAvg  THEN 'GoalAchieved'
      ELSE 'InProgress'
     END as Status,
 --3 month test 
 CASE WHEN CM > Last3MosAvg  THEN 'Winner'
      ELSE 'Loser'
     END as ThreeMonthStatus,

  CASE WHEN CM > LastSixmosAvg  THEN RANK () OVER (partition by Terrioty order by Sum(Revenue) desc)
```

Comment: hi, please only tag for the dbms you're using so we give you code that will run. Either mysql or sql server. Thanks!

Comment: I removed the mysql tag because it does not support window functions.  Also, sample data and desired results would clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: you add `CASE WHEN CM > LastSixmosAvg  THEN 'GoalAchieved'
      ELSE 'InProgress' END ` in your partition by?   `PARTITION BY CASE WHEN CM > LastSixmosAvg THEN 'GoalAchieved' ELSE 'InProgress' END, Terrioty ORDER BY SUM(Revenue) DESC`

Comment: What is wrong with the results of the query you posted?

Comment: That is close to my target, execpt its not really ranking records where CM<=LastSixMosAvg.

Comment: its not ranking by territory and by status. I need to rank "GoalsAchivers" in say "West" and "InProgress" in West. So I need 1,2,3,4 for "InProgress" records in the west and 1,2,3,4 for records in the east for both status that I am designating in my case when statement within the query

Comment: @JamieD77 your answer its very close, but how do I incorporate something similar to also rank records where CM <=LastSixMosAvg?